# COM interop not exposing some public classes

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, com-interop

I have a .NET project built with VS 2017. The option "Make assembly COM-visible" is selected and the assembly is strongly named. Some of my public classes, however, are not exposed to COM.

For example, assume my namespace is aa.bb.  Within this namespace I have various public classes, like foo, bar, and xyz.  I'm registering with regasm /codebase /tlb:test.tlb and it says it exported the tlb and registered successfully.

Checking the registry shows that only some of the public classes are exposed, while them most important public class is not.  For instance it has aa.bb.foo, and aa.bb.bar, but not aa.bb.xyz.

I ran regasm with /regfile:test.reg and it is not putting anything about the xyz class in there - only the foo and bar classes.  I also tried explictly listing it as com visible by doing this:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class xyz
```

however that made no difference.

From native .NET code like ASP.NET c# I can do "using aa.bb;" and then "xyz myObj = xyz.GetData();" and that works just fine. What are some of the reasons and things to look for as to why this class is not getting exposed to COM? How can I troubleshoot this further please? Thank you!

Comment: Post samples please, especially of the ones not showing up, but a contrast between what works and what does not will be educational as well.

Comment: COM has no support for static methods, an inevitable consequence of COM only ever using interfaces.  Remove the *static* keyword from the GetData() method declaration to get ahead.  Similarly, a [ComVisible] .NET class must have a public parameterless constructor.  Consider to create an xyz factory class for a more natural fit to an interface-based programming style.